# Cannot input dimension data table from pentaho to mysql

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I have a question regarding one problem within pentaho 8.2 version.
When I try to make dimension lookup/update I cannot select schema but I can create a table without spacifying that. Problem occurs when I look for this dimension table in mysql database that  I've just created in pentaho.
There is no data inside a dimension table but data must be there, so what should I do now to get this data inside mysql database?
I put some screenshoots with the steps so you could better understand me.

```
These are the steps I've made so far :
http://prntscr.com/nonxzn
http://prntscr.com/nony57
http://prntscr.com/nonyap
http://prntscr.com/nonyf0
http://prntscr.com/nonyju
http://prntscr.com/nonyse
http://prntscr.com/nonyvq
```

Comment: Don't put links to screenshoots.

Comment: To add to nacho's comment: You can add images to the post itself, please do that, focusing on the settings of the dimension lookup/update and the overall flow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use dots in your table names. It's a really, really bad idea. A dot is how you separate elements of an object, e.g. `schema.table.column`. Use underscores instead.

Also, what do you get when you run that transformation? Does it finish successfully?

If not, what errors are you getting? Your lookup/update step may be having trouble finding that table because of the dot in the name.